# Is this the limit of React without Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'd like to render a component to two separate routes -- one authenticated and editable, the other unauthenticated and read-only.

Currently all application state is in React and it's passed down to the final component and rendered.

If I want to render a copy of this component (with slightly different props to include read-only) -- on a different page, is that possible with only React and React Router?

Otherwise, do I need to use a central application store like Redux?

Conceptually I'm not sure how to pass props to the second component without rendering it on the page with the first component.

My goal is to have two similar but not identical versions of a component rendering to different routes.

Comment: At first glance, this sounds like the right fit for redux/an externalized store. It may be possible to externalize the `setState` method at your router level component to invoke re-rendering of components on both routes however that would feel like a definite anit-pattern to me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering a component to two routes, the correct answer was found on the backend.

Since I am using a serverless configuration, I wrote one lambda for an authenticated user and another lambda for an unauthenticated user.